# xsl regex with attribute failed recognition

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

This is my xml source. As you can see, it hasn't a regular structure - see the "auteur_5f_nom" here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<texte>
 <Standard/>
 <Standard/>
 <Standard>
  <auteur_5f_nom>auteur_nom XXX XXX </auteur_5f_nom>
  <auteur_5f_prenom>auteur_prenom XXX </auteur_5f_prenom>
  <date_5f_action>date_action 00/00/00 </date_5f_action>
  <date_5f_redaction>date_redaction 00/00/00 </date_5f_redaction>
  <mail/>
  <texteID>TexteID </texteID>
  <texteID>1234 </texteID>
   01 
 </Standard>
</texte>
```

... And later in the document source, the "auteur_5f_nom" tag:

```
</Standard>
<Standard/>
<Standard>
 <auteur_5f_nom>auteur_nom </auteur_5f_nom>
 <auteur_5f_nom>XXX </auteur_5f_nom>
 <auteur_5f_nom>auteur_prenom </auteur_5f_nom>
 <auteur_5f_prenom>XXX </auteur_5f_prenom>
 <date_5f_action>date_action 00/00/00 </date_5f_action>
 <date_5f_redaction>date_redaction 00/00/00 </date_5f_redaction>
 <mail/>
 <texteID>TexteID </texteID>
 <texteID>1234 </texteID>
  01
</Standard>
```

I would like to create an xsl transformation in order to have this output:

```
<paragraphe auteur_nom = "XXX XXX" auteur_prenom = "XXX" date_action = "00/00/00" texte_id = "205801"/>
```

the problem is: how can I create a regular XSL transformation in a bad formatted document like this, where the tag "auteur_5f_nom" can be:

```
1. <auteur_5f_nom>auteur_nom </auteur_5f_nom>
2. <auteur_5f_nom>auteur_nom XXX XXX </auteur_5f_nom>
3. <auteur_5f_nom>XXX </auteur_5f_nom>
4. <auteur_5f_nom>auteur_prenom </auteur_5f_nom>
```

?

Comment: Could you explain the **logic** by which the output needs to be derived from the given input? Your requested output shows only one `<p>` element, but your template produces five of them. And it's entirely not clear which part "works" and which doesn't. And there is no "some text" in your input..

Comment: I'm using a false text xml file because my file is a protected one so I can't post the real file. However I would like to create a new tag, which I called "p" as paragraph above, and transform the "tag" in my xml source to an attribute and use its text as value of the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to create a new tag, which I called "p" as paragraph above, and transform the "tag" in my xml source to an attribute and use its text as value of the attribute.

Is this what you're looking for?

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/test">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="tag">
       <p tag="{normalize-space(.)}">
           <xsl:text>some text</xsl:text>
       </p>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>
  <p tag="tag X">some text</p>
  <p tag="X">some text</p>
  <p tag="tag">some text</p>
  <p tag="X">some text</p>
  <p tag="tag2">some text</p>
</test>
```

Comment: I would like something like that   <p tag="X">some text</p>
  for all the <p tag>... That's my problem, I haven't found a way to have just the "x" and delete all values which aren't "X" (so "tag", "tag2", etc)

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are trying to achieve. Edit your question and **answer** the questions by @michael.hor257k (how is the input related to the output, what are the rules, why do you use regexes, what exactly does not work).

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create a new tag, which I called "p" as paragraph
>   above, and transform the "tag" in my xml source to an attribute and
>   use its text as value of the attribute.

If that's the gist of it, it could be accomplished very simply by:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <p>
        <xsl:attribute name="tag" select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

or, if you prefer a shorter one:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
    <p tag="{.}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

> it can't recognise the difference between "tag X" and just "tag ".

Your matches('.','tag\s.*') function says to find the text "tag", followed by a single whitespace, followed by "ZERO or MORE" characters anywhere in the string. Change the "*" to a "+" and you are now looking for "ONE or MORE" characters, which will now match the "tag X", but not the "tag ". Be aware though that the "." will match any character, including more whitespace. You might want to take the suggestions offered by others of using normalize-space() before doing your match compares.